# AJAX not submitting from external directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a star rating system on my application - the following code works correctly if it is in the PHP doc. But when I remove it and place it in a js file, it doesn't work.

Could someone please let me know why it's not working when i call the js file. Thanks.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.rate-btn').hover(function(){
    $('.rate-btn').removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
        var rating = $(this).attr('id');
        for (var i = rating; i >= 0; i--) {
        $('.rate-btn-'+i).addClass('rate-btn-hover');
    };
    });

$('.rate-btn').click(function(){    
var rating = $(this).attr('id');
var dataRate = 'act=rate&app_id=<?php echo $app_id; ?>&id=<?php echo $id; ?>&rate='+rating;
$('.rate-btn').removeClass('rate-btn-active');
for (var i = rating; i >= 0; i--) {
    $('.rate-btn-'+i).addClass('rate-btn-active');
};

$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : "submitRating.php", // I have tried changing this to reflect the directory
data: dataRate,
success:function(){}
});

});


});
</script>
```

Comment: remove the `<script></script>` from your js file perhaps?

Comment: in js file, you can't display php variable `var dataRate = 'act=rate&app_id=<?php echo $app_id; ?>&id=<?php echo $id; ?>&rate='+rating;`

Comment: Also , check  if the URL( relative path )in Ajax call is responsive.

Comment: @Se0ng11 I removed these in the external file

Comment: @TamilSelvan Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

> What "TamilSelvan" said is right you can't inject php code in js file. Try keeping the app_id and id in webstorage (or cookies) if you are redirection from some other page to this page and then make use of them in js file else first make AJAX call to retrieve app_id and id then use them.